# Horizontal Scrolling with MouseWheelListener

Tags: java, swing, scroll, mouseevent

I'm successfully able to catch and process vertical scrolling events in my application, by listening with my `MouseAdapter`.

Here's how:

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
{
   int n = e.getWheelRotation();
   //scroll n times
}
```

How do I similarly process horizontal scroll events, such as those generated on a trackpad?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that, as far as my testing has revealed, works on Mac but not Windows. Horizontal scrolling is interpreted the same way as vertical scrolling, albeit with <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down.

Thus overriding the following listener method does the job:

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
{
   int n = e.getWheelRotation();
   if(e.isShiftDown())
       //we've scrolled n times horizontally
   else
       //we've scrolled n times vertically.
}
```